# using "abs()" function in QGIS field calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I'm pretty new to GIS in general and I'm trying to take an absolute value of the difference between two fields in field calculator when creating a new field, but using ABS () returns an invalid expression in Preview. ABS () is not listed on the supported expressions--is there a way around this?
Thanks!
John

Answer (score 3):

You seem to use QGIS 1.8, because the development version (soon to be 2.0) supports **abs()**.

Instead, you can use

```
sqrt(value*value)
```

... replace value with your attribute.